# W/Gralloc3(12347): mapper 3.x is not supported ----how can i solve this?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, mapper

my flutter app currently running on my phone over usb .. but when I run my app it shows `W/Gralloc3(12347): mapper 3.x is not supported` how can I solve this problem ?